# How to copy screenshot from emulator to PC?

Tags: android, testing, automation, automated-tests, robotium

Am using Robotium for automation of android app testing. Using the command solo.takeScreenshot(), I was able to take screenshot and the image is stored in the SDcard > Robotium-screenshots folder in the emulator. Is there any way by which the image from the emulator can be copied to the PC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In DDMS View - Choose your device.

Click on the camera icon in below snapshot. Screenshot of device can be saved to PC directly.

[image]

to copy the existing files from emulator to PC, go to File Explorer in DDMS View and browse to your file, click on the icon in below snapshot.
[image]

Comment: Am using geny motion emulators, in file explorer am able to see a folder named sdcard but the folder is empty. But when am browsing to the same folder in emulator the screenshots are present in that. Do i need to do any other changes in the settings to view the images in file explorer in DDMS view.

Comment: Yes.. you are right. When the debug mode was enabled i was able to transfer the files by following the steps u have mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

try using adb commands

```
adb pull /sdcard/Robotium-Screenshots
```

files will be saved by default in adb folder (android-sdk\platform-tools)

Answer (score 0):

Do as shown in the images. step  by step

**Step 1:**[image]

[image]

In DDMS Select the devices.

**Step 2:**[image]

**Step 3:**[image]

Comment: I have already taken the screenshots of the emulator using the code solo.takeScreenshot() and its present in the sdcard>Robotium-screenshots folder. I need to know whether i can trasnfer those files from the device to PC.